# How to make size of polygon equal to size of window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have created a custom control( polygon) using windows form application. The code is:

```
public partial class shape7 : Control
{

    public Point p1 { get; set; }
    public Point p2 { get; set; }
    public Point p3 { get; set; }
    public Point p4 { get; set; }

    public shape7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        GraphicsPath _outline = new GraphicsPath();
        Point[] p = new Point[4]{new Point(p1.X,p1.Y),
        new Point(p2.X,p2.Y),
        new Point(p3.X,p3.Y),
        new Point(p4.X,p4.Y)};
        _outline.AddPolygon(p);            
        this.Region = new Region(_outline);
    }
```

where

```
p1 = 0,0
p2 = 100,0
p3 = 120,50
p4 = 20,0
```

Its giving me control like this:

[image]

as you can see in my Form1 the size of outer dotted window is not equal to my object polygon.

I want that if in increase the size of window than the object size should also get increase.

Please suggest how to do this.

Also i Want the default color of this object to black or blue.

Comment: I edited your question. Please, do not append greetings and tags that are not relevant to questions (as IDE is not for your question).

Comment: Okay after 8 hours research got the answer, we can inherit the the property of base object and assign it to current object. using base